# AWS/Node.js S3 Signed URL Denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon's Node.js `aws-sdk` to create expiring pre-signed S3 URLs for digital product downloads, and struggling with the result. I've got the SDK configured with my keys successfully, and I've tried both a synchronous approach (not shown) and an async approach (shown) at collecting signed urls. The calls work, I never hit any errors and I am successfully returned signed URLs. Here's the twist: the URLs I get back don't work.

```
const promises = skus.map(function(sku) {
  const key = productKeys[sku];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: 'my-products',
      Key: key,
      Expires: 60 * 60 * 24, // Time in seconds; 24 hours
    }, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve({
          text: productNames[sku],
          url: res,
        });
      }
    });;
  });
});
```

I had assumed it was an error with the keys I had allocated, which I had assigned to an IAM User who has full S3 bucket access. So, I tried using a root level keypair and I get the same access denied result. Interestingly: the URLs I get back take the form `https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/Path/To/My/Product.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=blahblahMyKey&Expires=43914919&Signature=blahblahmysig&x-amz-security-token=hugelongstring`. I've not seen this `x-amz-security-token` thing before, and if I try just removing that query param, I get Access Denied but for a different reason: the AWSAccessKeyId is one that is not associated with any of my accounts. It's not the one I've configured the SDK with and it's not one I've allocated on my S3 account. No idea where it comes from, and no idea how that relates to the `x-amz-security-token` param.

Anyway, I'm stumped. I just want a working pre-signed url... what gives? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @ncthom91. Have you found a solution to this? I'm having the same problem.